# How to get Blender to record animation from game engine consistently?

Tags: animation, game-engine

Blender has a feature to record animations from the game engine:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/physics/introduction.html

I have used this in the past, and have managed to get it to work but it seems flaky. As of now I can't get it to record a scene I'm making. I have tried removing all the previous keyframes, turning off and then turning on the option to record animation, and such, but it still just runs the game without recording any keyframes.

Now running Blender 2.79.

Any assistance in how to get Blender to record animation from the game engine?

EDIT: I just tried again, this time pressing Enter (a key with a sensor in this scene), and it seems to have recorded two objects, although none of the others, and so far it hasn't been reproduceable.

Some further details of the bizarre behavior: It seems that playing the animation (alt-A) after recording it makes some keyframes appear, whereas before playback (but after recording) no keyframes appear. Even still, it's only for two of the objects -- there are many more here, including some starting in this scene and others added to the scene through game logic.

The two objects that do get animated both start in this scene rather than getting added to it by the "Edit Object" actuator, and move in the scene. Perhaps the objects not getting animated are those that are static and those that get added to the scene by the "Edit Object" actuator?

After another test, a new object that starts in this scene and moves does not get recorded. Also, the moving camera has not been recorded. It seems that it does not add new keyframes when there already are keyframes, even after playback (alt-A).

Here only two objects have had animations recorded, even though numerous other objects get animated. Of the two visible objects in the following screenshot, neither is an animated sphere. One is an icosphere that I deliberately added to test, and its motion fails to get recorded:

[image: Here only two objects have had animations recorded, even though numerous other objects get animated.]

A fresh take, after removing previous keyframes:

[image: A fresh take, after removing previous keyframes.]

Here the game has obviously played, yet keyframes for the moving parts are not recorded:

[image: Here the game has obviously played, yet keyframes for the moving parts are not recorded.]

Comment: can you put a example image ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've edited the question to add images. Please let me know of anything else useful.

Comment: good , now i can check

Comment: I see, I have similar problems, although mine is at the src level I want to repair that detail and while more info from other people get more I will understand this
I had consulted this video, but it does with python scripts, I've been working sporadically on this with python but without much success, almost everyone tells you that you can not, but try changing to

Comment: Rigid Body & Soft Body. If you don't want to record animations, you can use Physics Type: Character

Comment: https://youtu.be/NJt7aZcLB90 use scripts python

Comment: https://youtu.be/I2Z7BneNnFk

Comment: something I do not understand well is about the frames, because he does not create them, nobody has been able to explain exactly how this works in bge

Comment: Thatinmst3r have a good example https://youtu.be/GH48Dnr5cq4

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/record-100-animations-in-bge/581581 check this in blender arti